# Vim Fuzzy Finder like for Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I'm trying Emacs again, after saw the combination of `company+alchemist`. And again I'm struggling to find alternatives to some Vim plugins. One of the biggest difficulties is file navigation. With `fuzzy finder`(https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) I can find a file in any place, only search by his name. I searched hard but can't find anything similar to `fuzzy finder/ctrlp` in Emacs. There is a good replacement of `fuzzy finder` for Emacs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an [Emacs frontend for fzf](https://github.com/bling/fzf.el) as well. You can install it from ELPA (`M-x list-packages`, navigate to `fzf`, press `i` then `x` to install). You need to [download the `fzf` program separately](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf-bin/releases), if you don't already have it.

Alternatively, try out [Helm](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Helm) (also available from ELPA). Read [this tutorial](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html). It provides the same services as fzf and much more (because it isn't limited to finding files), in its own way.

Comment: You could also use [Ivy](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) instead of Helm, which, although maybe a little less powerful, appears to work faster (and for me is powerful anough). To quickly find a file in any place, use the `counsel-locate` (or `helm-locate`) command. Just remember to run `sudo updatedb` regularly...

Answer (score 2):

I have combined the two from @tjbruno answer. https://github.com/ibmandura/helm-fzf/blob/master/helm-fzf.el

Here you can use fzf with helm as frontend :)

Comment: isn't this using helm's fuzzy matching algorithm ? fzf it self has a sorter and a matcher and there is no point of using helms because in my experience it is less accurate that fzf's

Comment: @static removing "--no-sort" flag and "requires-pattern" turned helm-fzf precise as using fzf.vim to me